# c# about interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, reference, guid

I have a library that contains some public interfaces. Before each public interface there is a: [Guid:("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx")]. What is this Guid. what does it do? Is it possible to acces the methods from this library without adding the lib to ref just using this Guid. Or what can i do using another application with this Guid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This GUID is used when the .NET assembly is used as an COM object. You can't use this method without referencing either the .NET assembly as a .NET assembly or as a COM object. This is mainly for interoperability with other languages that don't know how to work with .NET assemblies. COM objects can be consumed by virtually any technology/language on Windows.

Comment: what do you mean by .net assembly. I just want to run an exe and based with this guid to do somethig. it is possible?

Comment: Every exe or dll that is using the .NET framework is called an .NET assembly. Just reference the .NET assembly you saw these GUIDs in, in your exe and use those methods like you would use any other .NET method.

Comment: i see. if i am executing an exe file using process.start, how can i communicate with that exe from another application based on these guids? I mean if i want to post a message in the exe how should i use the GUID?

Comment: elisa, please understand that this is not possible. Those GUIDs are identifiers in the COM world. They identify a method or class, just like "System.Data.Oracle.EFOracleProviderFactory, System.Data.Oracle, Version=0.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=388e67544b406623" identifies a class in the .NET world.

Comment: To communicate with your EXE, the EXE needs to support it, e.g. by supporting interprocess communication (IPC) with Shared Pipes, WCF, .NET Remoting, ordinary TCP/IP etc. etc.

Comment: i see. ok thx. i have one more qustion: what is the differen between postmessage and sendkey. with sendkey the string pops up into the running app , but with postmessage i dont see anything. why?

Comment: elisa, this is not the topic of this question and sendkey and postmessage are just completely different things. sendkey is the same as pressing a key on your keyboard. postmessage is sending a windows message to the window. What happens, when you do this, depends on the message sent. Please post any further questions as new questions and not in the comments of this one. Finally, if I could help you a bit, please accept my answer...

Comment: thx Daniel. I did accept your answer. Thx a lot:) Coudl i ask youone more thing about post message? plz:)...If i excute a process with process.start() and after that if i want to post a message to a secondary form application what sould i do? I mean i have an exe which runs form1. after process.start the form1 pops up.  i click form2 whrere i want to post a message. what should i write in post message code? THx!!

Comment: @elisa: Please ask it as a new question. You will get a lot more answers and probably answers that are more qualified than mine. It has been quite some time since I last used PostMessage.